# Why aren't the stock and mainline kernels supporting Intel onboard graphics when the 20.04b kernel does? Z590 motherboard 11th gen i9 11900k

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, graphics, intel-graphics

**EDIT: Problem with display has been narrowed down to dual montitors. System will only boot into both monitors on the OEM kernel listed below. For ALL other kernels, including 5.12.2, and the latest MESA drivers I have to unplug one monitor until I reach the desktop.**

Title sort of says it all.

Kernels tried:
5.10.0.1023-oem (20.04b) dual displays work, NICs stuck at 1gb.

5.10 stock fail,
5.11 fail,
5.8 fail,
5.4 fail,
5.12 fail,
5.12.1 released today, fail.

All of the failing kernels will boot to a add in graphics card. And they will boot in safe mode. 5.11 and 5.12 also report an hdaudio issue at boot up and then hang there.

Kubuntu 21.04 USB install stick fails but will boot with safe graphics.

Base OS install was server 20.04 on a Linux raid array using two m.2 drives. Xubuntu and Ubuntu Studio desktops added, the later without the low latency kernel. I used the server install because for some reason you can't build linux raid arrays with the desktop intaller, another failure IMHO.

Hardware:

Asus Rog Strix Z590e gaming

11900k i9 CPU running at 5.4ghz

64gb 3200mhz ram

360mm Corsair AIO cooler

Two Samsung Evo 980 PCIe 4.0 M.2 drives in Linux raid 0

Samsung Evo 970 M.2 scratch drive

LSI raid controller with 6 3tb enterprise drives in raid 5 and 2 Samsung Evo SATA drives for SSD raid cacheing. Onboard battery backup.

Dual 32" monitors

And just because I'm old school an IBM model M PS/2 keyboard with an active USB adapter. Still the greatest keyboard ever made....

I went with Intel because of its historically good support in Linux. I went with the 11th gen i9 for PCIe 4.0 support despite poor performance compared to new AMD CPUs because first it had onboard graphics and I'm not paying scalper prices for an AMD chip or an Nvidia GPU. I don't really need a GPU for much anyway. Also my older PCs tend to become my new home servers and I prefer onboard graphics for that reason. My old 3770k is happily chugging along as a server now after 9 years of abuse from me. Video card removed and sold. I also have a 10700k on a Z490 board that runs onboard graphics and 2.5gb Ethernet just fine.

Bottom line, can anyone explain why the developers are not including whatever driver they put in 5.10.0.1023-oem in newer mainline or stock kernels? I mean 5.12.1 is already out and still no love for new Intel hardware. Very little is mentioned about this online.

So now I am running 21.04 stripped of its stock kernel and still running the 20.04b oem kernel. It complains of outdated binaries when I install software.

Normally I would blame Intel, and for the NIC and audio I still do but with 20.04b kernel working I have to wonder what's up with the devs?

If you are a dev I will HAPPILY beta test your patch's. I'll jump through all the hoops you need. Let's get this working on 5.12.x please!!!

dmseg output:

```
chris@pc-01:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i i915
[    0.781293] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    0.782900] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: 
olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    0.783311] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware 
i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_02.bin (v2.2)
[    0.854517] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20200917 for 0000:00:02.0 
on minor 0
[    0.918948] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.008889] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer 
device
[    7.856496] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-
a552d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops 
[i915])
[    7.876177] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops 
i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
```

and relevant part of lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 
4c8a(rev04)
```

So yes it is a 4c8a and with this kernel (20.04b) its running rkl_dmc_ver2_02.bin (v2.2) for a driver it appears.

UPDATE:
I finally got a chance to fully read both Phoronix articles on benchmarks as well as the article on P-states. Of note, my new bios fixed the weirdness of P-states with powersave now giving me full CPU performance. However some things I find odd. My CPU is lapped as is my Corsair H150i Pro XT AIO, anything above 300 watts and I start to thermal throttle in heavy benchmarks like Handbrake. I am disappointed in the stock fans on my AIO and have some high static pressure Noctua fans coming in today. Still though the author was able to hit 385 watts in his testing with a NH-U9S cooler. He does state he had some random reboots when running that hot but WOW I find it hard to believe an air cooler is handling this CPU better than my 360mm AIO and plenty of case airflow. I'm also running a gold rated 1000 watt PSU for clean power delivery. If past experience is any indicator my fan upgrade will help a bunch. But I'm also using Conductanaut liquid metal on my lapped block and CPU. That alone was good for a 5-7C drop before the new bios came out allowing me to run over 300 watts. Of further, and more relevant note: the author was running 5.12 kernel and Mesa 21.1 drivers. To boot the 5.12 kernel he needed to use force_probe. Well my system will simply not boot 5.12 with the onboard graphics aside from safe mode. I have no clue from his articles what he is doing differently. I do have a low end GPU I can throw in to do some poking around in 5.12 but that still doesn't solve my issue of ONLY being able to boot boot monitors on the onboard graphics using kernel 20.04b aka 5.10.0.1023-oem.

Related articles:
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-rkl-linux&num=1
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-11900k-pstate&num=1

EDIT: Fixed "I also have a 10700k on a Z490 board that runs onboard graphics and 2.5gb Ethernet just fine." to say Z490 and not Z590.

Update: 5/8/2021. I have discovered if I used "i915.force_probe=4c8a" in grub with 5.12, 5.12.1, 5.12.2, linux next, kernels etc I can boot ONE monitor only. For booting dual monitors using both ports I still must run the 20.04b (5.10.0.1023-oem) kernel. However, something weird: I booted into 5.12.2 on the HDMI connected monitor, runs fine, so just for a test I plugged in the DP monitor and not only did it come up but it gave me my expanded desktop. ?????

Update 6/5/2021 5.11.0-19-generic now supports dual monitors

Comment: Even mainline takes some time to support the newest Intel parts. You will have to be patient. Watch for mainline kernel 5.13-RC1 in one week, or try the mainline dailies. You might find what you are looking for in one of the "drm" Ubuntu mainline PPA sub-directories, for example the [specific intel nighty](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-intel-nightly/) one. But note it does take time before this stuff gets merged with the master, and even more time until it is backported to Ubuntu kernels.

Comment: Gen12 Xe Graphics might not be working out-of-the-box depending upon your kernel. 
Re-booting the system while having "i915.force_probe=4c8a" Some distribution kernels including the likes of Ubuntu are already carrying the patch 
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-rkl-linux&num=1
Please don't mention i915.force_probe in end-user documentation #980 
https://github.com/intel/media-driver/issues/980 & 
https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DRM_I915_FORCE_PROBE.html

Comment: force_probe will enable one monitor at full resolution, leaving the other blank.

@DougSmythies I tried the nightlies, and linux-next, even complied my own with an intel patch I thought would work.

I suppose what is frustrating is 20.04b (oem) works. Why not throw us a bone and put out a 21.04b so my PC will stop complaining about old binaries when I install software.?

With the shortage of gpus and scalper prices I can't be the only one facing this problem.

Comment: After seeing that great reference from @oldfred, and if you didn't already, try [drm-next](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/drm-next/). For binaries use that reference I pointed you before and remember that a lot of the complaining  wouldn't be relevant to your processor.

Comment: @DougSmythies Given your interest in power consumption you may find this article interesting: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-11900k-pstate&num=1 synopsis: enabling performance mode resulted in much higher performance but at a high power price, up to 385 watts! When the 11900k was released it received negative reviews based on benchmarks, I wonder how much of that is unfair given there is clearly lacking software support. 

Trying drm-next, compiling now. Thank you.

Comment: @oldfred I don't fully understand your last link. Where do those options go? In grub or in the .config file before you compile?

I guess I don't understand the oem kernel process or the kernel dev process in general. To a newbie like me it seems simple, whatever they did in 20.04b-oem implement into a 21.04b-oem and let people try it out. I mean it seems obvious to me. It also seems obvious to me that given how much development intel does they would want a working kernel for their new flagship CPU especially in light of all the bad press it's gotten.

Comment: I do not know details. It looks like driver is supposed to be compiled into kernel, so boot parameter is not required and should only be used by developers. The boot parameter is like nomodeset. I might replace quiet splash on Linux line in grub. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: @oldfred It says in use for kernels 5.3-5.12, I've tried a bunch in that range and none work unless I put the force_probe in grub, but then I only get one monitor when my board supports two. I stopped my git clone of drm-next, that repo is dated 2018. Getting this one to try: git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack cod/mainline/cod/tip/drm-intel-next/2021-04-30
I'll see what it does.

Comment: Well drm-intel-next kernel did not work. Any kernel above the oem 5.10.0-1023 kernel hangs on boot at fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from VGA EFI. If I boot 5.9 with the force_probe get a single monitor. I searched for that fb0: error and tried multiple things by selecting "e" in grub, like getting rid of force_probe and glx etc. Nothing works for the newer kernels.

Comment: Related [Ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1905466).

Comment: @DougSmythies I've seen that but tonight was the first time I could comment somewhat intelligently on it. I'm thinking I will sign up at phoronix and email the author of that article I posted and just ask what kernel and how many monitors did they use when benchmarking. I mean they obviously had a working system. Can't hurt.

Comment: Does yours show exactly same model, from Phoronix p2 in link. `sudo dmesg | grep -i i915` and his was the '4c8a' which he then used in the boot parameter. His page 3 shows this: Tests were done on Ubuntu 21.04 with the Linux 5.12 Git kernel and Mesa 21.1-devel.  Many of his reviews use the newest kernels & drivers from Oibaf PPA. Older link where he discusses that a bit more. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTY1NTU May have been updated since, not sure. May want to search his site for all Xe info.

Comment: @oldfred updated the post with the requested dmesg info.

Comment: I should have mentioned I have used the Oilaf PPA. Suppose I could boot into 5.12.1 and see if they are being used.

Comment: Updated the OP, some weirdness going on.

Comment: Is there any possibility this could be related to the base install being Ubuntu Server 20.04? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: Added an interesting update at the end.

Comment: Update: 5.11.0-19-generic now supports dual monitors