# Boot logs? Where can I look to figure out why my system will boot dual monitors with an OEM kernel but not any others?

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Related to this topic: [Why aren't the stock and mainline kernels supporting Intel onboard graphics when the 20.04b kernel does? Z590 motherboard 11th gen i9 11900k](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335529/why-arent-the-stock-and-mainline-kernels-supporting-intel-onboard-graphics-when?noredirect=1#comment2279866_1335529)

My new 11th gen i9 will boot to the desktop with dual monitors using kernel 5.10.0-1023-oem (20.04b) but for other kernels I have to unplug either monitor and can plug it back in after I am on the desktop. I am trying to figure out where to look to compare what is happening with the OEM kernel vs the mainline and stock kernels.

I don't know where to begin or what to look for. Hoping to figure out what is configured differently in boot up on the OEM vs. other kernels.

UPDATE: Same issue with 5.13-rc1 which I just installed. Hangs at "fb0: switching to inteldrmfb from VGA EFI". This one doesn't need a config line added to grub for force_probe of the i915 driver.

Comment: It's usually not a *configuration* issue. OEM kernels are a temporary workaround (a partnership between Canonical and your hardware OEM) to get new hardware compatibility fast. When your hardware is compatible with the mainline kernel, and when that kernel is incorporated into a future Ubuntu release, then that specific OEM kernel will be discontinued in favor of the generic kernel. Until then, advice is to stick to your OEM kernel. Haywiring something else is a great way to lose that compatibility.

Comment: @user535733 that makes some sense. It just seems to me like there is one line somewhere in the OEM kernel that is enabling dual monitors and if I could add that line or even file to a kernel compile I'd be good to go. FYI my machine is not OEM, it's custom built on an Asus motherboard. Longer term plan is to add a GPU when availability comes back.  I'm using the OEM kernel because it's the only one that works. The stock and mainline kernels hang in text if I don't unplug one monitor, that's why I suspect there is some sort of simple solution if I can find where to look.